# routing between child and parent component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i have two components ,I want that when i click the button go to quizz he takes me to the child component Is there any solutions because routing didn't work I have an example that is working:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="startCourse()">Start Course</button>
```

and in typescript:

```
public startCourse()
  {
    if(this.permitted_courses.includes(this.course_code)) {
      this.router.navigate(['courses/learn'] , {queryParams : { 'course' : this.course_id}});
    }
    else {
      this.router.navigate(['payment'],{queryParams : { 'course' : this.course_id}});
    }
  }
```

this project is angular and spring boot

Comment: What part of routing did not work for you? What was the expected and actual behavior?

Comment: I juste want to go from the parent component( Course learn) to child(quizz) ,the code that I posted 100% working ,Can I do something  similar for the quizz, I Create another typescript function Startquizz() but not working in the routing i did:  {
        path : 'courseLearn/:Quizz',
        component: QuizzPageComponent
      },

Comment: Can you show your routing module where the routes are declared and initialized? Maybe your project doesn't know `courses/learn` or `payment`

Comment: RouterModule.forRoot([
      
      {
        path : 'user/:type',
        component : LoginpageComponent
      },
      {
        path : 'courses/all-courses',
        component: CoursesPageComponent
      },
      {
        path : 'course/:course',
        component: CoursesDetailsPageComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'courses/learn',
        component: CourselearnpageComponent
      },
      
      
      {
        path: 'quizz', component: QuizzComponent
      },

Comment: const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{enableTracing:true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

Comment: now the quizz page is working but when i try to put it in course learn component it dosen't work

Comment: I make a button quizz in the home page so it work and it takes me to the quizz page

Comment: Is course/:course a typo and it rewlly is courses/:course? If so, move route for courses/learn before route for courses/:course. Generic routes with id should be last in the tree to not activate other routes